# SQLite.swift framework

Tags: ios, sql, swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

This function not working !!!
I can add some other functions if your want
I got problem with saving, its not working

Output - "Connected Ok
The operation couldn’t be completed. (SQLite.Result error 0.)"

```
let db = try Connection("\(path)/database.sqlite3")
print("Connected Ok")

let nameTemp1 = Expression<String>("namePoint")
let latTemp1 = Expression<Double>("lat")
let longTemp1 = Expression<Double>("long")
let addressTemp1 = Expression<String?>("address")
let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
try db.run(TempPointOriginal.create(ifNotExists: true) { t in
    t.column(id, primaryKey: true)
    t.column(nameTemp1)
    t.column(latTemp1)
    t.column(longTemp1)
    t.column(addressTemp1)
})

try db.run(TempPointOriginal.insert(/*or: .replace,*/ nameTemp1 <- name1))
try db.run(TempPointOriginal.insert(/*or: .replace,*/ latTemp1 <- lat1))
try db.run(TempPointOriginal.insert(/*or: .replace,*/ longTemp1 <- long1))
try db.run(TempPointOriginal.insert(/*or: .replace,*/ addressTemp1 <- address1))
```

Comment: I don’t use [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift), but 0 is generally not an error, `SQLITE_OK`, so this is a little curious. But it seems a little suspicious to do separate `.insert` calls for the individual fields. I’d do those in a single `.insert` (or, if it exists, a single `.replace`). E.g. I would have thought it would be `try db.run(TempPointOriginal.insert(nameTemp1 <- name1, latTemp1 <- lat1, longTemp1 <- long1, addressTemp1 <- address1))`. See that repo’s example of `try db.run(users.insert(name <- "Alice", email <- "alice@mac.com"))`.

Comment: BTW, which line is throwing that error? Either single step through your code or add log statements so you can figure out exactly which line is throwing it. Also, where are you printing that “The operation couldn’t be completed” message? I assume this is wrapped in a `do`-`catch` statement and that this is printed in the `catch`, but you haven’t shared that with us so it’s a bit unclear. Seeing that “The operation couldn’t be completed. (SQLite.Result error 0.)” makes me wondering whether you printed the error outside of the `catch` block or after some other SQL, losing the error details.

Comment: There is no error, just there is no saving my data, its Empty in result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you need to fix or at least consider with your code. When you create a column like this

```
let nameTemp1 = Expression<String>("namePoint")
```

you are saying it is mandatory (not null), to make it optional the type has to be optional, `<String?>`

```
let nameTemp1 = Expression<String?>("namePoint")
```

So this is something you might want to change in your table

Secondly your insert is wrong since you are actually performing 4 inserts but only one column at a time has been given a value and with all columns mandatory this generates an error. So unless you make your columns optional all values must be given for an insert statement

```
try db.run(TempPointOriginal.insert(nameTemp1 <- name1, 
                                    latTemp1 <- lat1, 
                                    longTemp1 <- long1, 
                                    addressTemp1 <- address1))
```